# updating a worksheet with another sheets values

Tags: excel, vlookup

This might be easy for you but i need to use one vlookup formula since i am dealing with many numbers in two Columns.

I have two sheets one of them is Sheet1 other one is Sheet2

Both of them have two columns. Columns A contains "Materialnumber" and Column B contains "Status". Sheet1 has more "Materialnumbers" inside then Sheet2
but Sheet2 includes correct "Status", so thatswhy if "Materialnumbers" are matching i would  like to have the "Status" value of Sheet2 in Sheet1's Column C.

I know i should write the vlookup code in Sheet1's Column C. But what is the right formula for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You're right - just a VLOOKUP needed in column C.
In C2 put this formula:

`=VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet2!$A$1:$B$12,2,FALSE)`

- It looks at the value in Sheet1 A2.
- Compares that value against the first column in the range $A$1:$B$12 (update the range as required).
- Returns the value from the second column (B).
- Only returns on an exact match (FALSE).

Answer (score 0):

Try this in cell `C2` on Sheet1:

`=VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet2!A:B,2,0)`

Comment: thanks a lot. how can i do the same for not matching columns ? i want to take the "status " of the materialnumbers which are not matching this time ?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the question, do you mean that you would like to take the status already in Sheet1 if there is no match for the materialnumber in Sheet2? If so you'd want a formula like: `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet2!A:B,2,0),$B2)`